# How to solve: macbook pro loading only after login & login password input field is yellowish and strange

Tags: macbook-pro, login

As always, every time I would turn my macbook pro on it would have the following actions:

- Black screen
- White apple pops up
- Loading bar runs
- Login screen shows up, with my wallpaper, chosen language set up, battery indicator that is being charged(if on the charger)
- Then I am logged in normally

A few days ago it started to act strange.

When I start the macbook this is the following behaviour:

- Black Screen
- White apple
- Login screen totally deconfigured: The password field has an yellowish background color, on the top right the language is not my chosen set up, the battery, even if charging, does not show the energy indicator, the background image is the default one at the macbook default image that only should pop up if I had more then one user set on the computer, which is not the case, as I am being directed to my user, as there is only one user set(the admin), so I should get my wallpaper(my user's wallpaper), and not this default one.
- When I type the password and login the loading bar appears
- Then it gets in the account and the rest is normal

When I tried using the safe mode:

- black screen
- white apple
- Same weird login screen
- I enter my password
- Loading bar shows up
- Safe mode login shows up, for the same user, as there is only one set up on the machine. I have to re-type my username and password.
- User is logged in and the rest is normal

I hope I managed to make myself clear regarding the issue.

Has anyone ever experienced this before?

[image][image]

Comment: Has macOS recently been updated? The yellow login field may be due to the color on the wallpaper behind it, which is mainly yellow.

Comment: Enabled FileVault recently?

Comment: @Harcker nope. This background image should not be appearing at all. This is the image that should appear if I had more than one user set. Then this image should appear with the users. This is not the image set for my admin user... And I have never seen this yellowish background color for the login. Its not inheriting the colours from the image as well as can be easily figured by looking at the pic.

Comment: @klanomath It is on. But now I do not have an idea for how long it has been on. Not sure when did I turn it on. I am turning it off here to check if this is the issue. When fileVault is on is there this kind of password checking when turning the macbook on?

Comment: @Alioshr Assuming your boot volume is APFS (10.13/10.14/10.15) your common desktop pic isn't really available because the main system volume is still encrypted and has to be unlocked first.

Comment: @klanomath it was the issue! The FileVault had to be disabled and the I also had to set the initial display to "list of users". Now I am getting my single user login page, with my wallpaper, correct startup phases, etc. Thanks very much. Do you wanna make this your answer, so I can rate it for you?

Comment: my macbook is 2017, so I assume that it is available in case the FileVault is active